# SQL count of return users

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hue

I'm trying to return a count of return users which happens when there is a duplicate 'user_id and action_type'.

So if you refer below, I would like my output to be = 2, since user_id (5) has 2 similar action_types (234) and user_id (6) also has 2 similar action_types (585).

How do I structure my query to reflect this?

```
Table t1
User_Id     Action_Type
---------   ------------
5           234
5           846
5           234
6           585
6           585 
7           465
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_Id) FROM (
  SELECT   User_Id
  FROM     t1
  GROUP BY User_Id, Action_Type
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(User_ID) DuplicateRecordsUsers
FROM 
(SELECT User_ID, Action_Type, COUNT(User_ID) Records
FROM     Table    
GROUP BY  User_ID, Action_Type
HAVING COUNT(User_ID) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(User_Id) FROM (
  SELECT   User_Id
  FROM     t1
  GROUP BY User_Id, Action_Type
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
) t
```

`DISTINCT` not required just count the ids returned

Comment: `DISTINCT` is required.  Imagine if `(5, 846)` appeared an extra time in the OP's example data: then `User_Id = 5` would be returned twice by the subquery (once for each `Action_Type`); thus distorting the overall count.